# How to get the first element of multicolumn combo box into grid view?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, telerik, runtime-error

I'm using *telerik grid view* and *multi column combo box*

i want to get the first element of combo box and insert it in the first cell of the grid view and then insert it into DB

i get a run time error when i select the combo box element

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

here is where it occurs (in the last line)

```
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

and here's my code which leads to this run time error

```
private void radMultiColumnComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text;
        text = radMultiColumnComboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString();
        radGridView1.Rows.Add(Text);
    }
```

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/447156)

Comment: @SonerGönül i am so confused,can you tell me where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the first element of the combo box is not necessarily in the `SelectedValue`.

```
text = radMultiColumnComboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString(); //this doesn't get the first value
```

As the name implies, the `SelectedValue` is the selected value of the combo box, it is not its first element.

Secondly, it is possible for your `ComboBox` **not** to have selected value and having `SelectedValue == null`. Thus `SelectedValue.ToString()` cannot performed.

To see if a `ComboBox` has item, uses `Items.Count`

```
if (radMultiColumnComboBox3.MultiColumnComboBoxElement.Rows.Count > 0){
    //do something, item exists
    //check also SelectedIndex of the combo box, if it is == -1, nothing is selected
} else {
    //This combobox does not have any item
}
```

As to get the first element, you can do something like this,

```
var item = radMultiColumnComboBox3.MultiColumnComboBoxElement.Rows[0]; //item is the first element, provided the count > 0
```

Comment: visual studio doesn't know (item)

Comment: maybe you can take as object first, then cast it to something else. I edited my answer

Comment: I did look at you're answer,What do mean by casting?

Comment: Type Casting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx. change from one class type to another like `int b = 5; double a = (double)b;`

Comment: it still doesn't know the item

Comment: Maybe you can post the image/description of the new error?

Comment: this is the error ['Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadMultiColumnComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadMultiColumnComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99224/discussion-between-ian-and-mostafa-bouzari).